# How to create a cuvilinear line segment with loess and lines using R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, loess

I am trying to fit a curved line segment to a dataset. While I can create the line it is always connected back to the starting point. I can't figure out how to get rid of this. I would really appreciate any help. Here is the code

```
mscF25=c(-12.94382785, -11.0281518, -9.186403952, -7.691576905, -6.470229134, -5.43000796, -4.559074508, -12.87271022, -10.0646268, -6.796208225, -4.433351598, -2.928135666, -1.979265556, -1.38936463, -11.05819006, -7.785838826, -5.297330858, -3.674159165, -2.64702678, -1.980973252, -1.533714976, -11.83971039, -9.168353808, -6.89192172, -5.23424594, -4.033326594, -3.148798626, -2.480469911)
bscF25=c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
df25 <- data.frame(bscF25,mscF25)
plot(mscF25 ~ bscF25, data = df25)
ls25 <- loess(mscF25 ~ bscF25, data = df25, span = 3)
lines(df25$bscF25, ls25$fitted)
```

[image: This is what I get. I would like to keep the curved line but get rid of the straight section connecting it.]

Comment: And for the next time, please make it easier for people trying to help you by providing a minimal, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). It makes it so much easier with some data to play around with to understand what the problem is and to try out potential solutions. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the `scatter.smooth` function: "Plot and add a smooth curve computed by loess to a scatter plot"

```
scatter.smooth(x = df25$bscF25, y = df25$mscF25, span = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried with more specific variables and specified the data frame, but still got the same result. I updated the code above so that hopefully it is more reproducible. If you have any other suggestions I would really appreciate it.